# PHP - call a function from a img src

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Want to render an image without saving it to disk using PHP GD libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239286/want-to-render-an-image-without-saving-it-to-disk-using-php-gd-libs)
>   [The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385982/the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors)

I'd like to call a function that make a image trought the img src tag. Is it possible?

I mean : instead of call `<img src="path/file.php" />` I'd like to do somethings like `<img src="function()" />`

Comment: Technically, it is possible using `data:` URI's but it's a terrible idea. Go with what @Sjoerd suggests

Comment: See a possible solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385982/the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors/3386050#3386050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is server side; It can *generate* either a base64_encoded image result which can be placed as an image, or you can point to a php script that will generate an image. But, regarding client side, it won't work.

So, you *could* do the following:

```
// the browser will make a call to your generator to render an image back
echo '<img src="myimagegenerator.php" />';

// src will be something like "data:image/png;base64,..."
echo '<img src="'.generateImage().'" />';
```

Comment: @Gordon: Semantics, but done. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5 you can put the base64 encoded image source in an image tag. You will just need a function to return that.

```
function getImage($file){
      return 'data:image/gif;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
}
```

Your img tag:

```
<img src="<? echo getImage('path-to-image.gif'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

However, you can use the URL "thispage.php?makeimage=1" and call the function and output an image if `$_GET['makeimage']` contains 1.

Comment: -1 because it **is** possible with data URIs