# using <img> tag to call PHP script for displaying encoded image retrieved from database

Tags: php, html, image

My PHP script for storing the encoded image data in a database table as a 'blob' type:

```
include './libraries/LIB_mysql.php'; # library for using the 'insert()' function at the end
$imageFilePath = "./pythonProgrammingProgram.PNG";
$imageFileRead = file_get_contents($imageFilePath); # == �PNG  IHDR�A ... uY�IEND�B`� (... and so on)
$imageEncode = base64_encode($imageFileRead); # iVBORw0KGgoAAAA (... and so on)
$data_array['image_id'] = 3;
$data_array['image_file'] = $imageEncode;
$table = 'images';
insert(DATABASE, $table, $data_array);
```

The image data seems to get stored correctly in the database:

```
mysql> select * from images;
| image_id | image_file
|        3 | iVBORw0KGgoAAAA # (... and so on)
```

I would like then to get the image displayed within an HTML page using 'img' tag, which calls a PHP script: `<img src="./imageDisplay.php?pictureID=3">`.
The PHP script `imageDisplay.php` retrieving the image data from the database and echoing the decoded image:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
include('./libraries/LIB_mysql.php'); # for using exe_sql() function
$image_id = $_GET['pictureID']; # == 3 -> corresponds to the value in the database !!
$sql = "SELECT image_file FROM images WHERE image_id = '" . $image_id . "'"; # $image_id";
list($img) = exe_sql(DATABASE, $sql); # $img contains the decoded data: == �PNG  IHDR�A ... uY�IEND�B`� (... and so on)
echo base64_decode($img);
exit;
```

When loading the HTML file on the localhost, I see the broken image. In Firefox under Network -> Response I see:

```
Name: imageDisplay.php
Dimensions: 0 × 0
MIME Type: image/png
```

I guess the transferring of the image data did not function, but I can't really see why. The decoded image data in `base64_decode($img)` is the same as in `$imageFileRead` before the encoding, so I guess the database operations are not the issue, but somewhere in `echo base64_decode($img);` or `<img src="./imageDisplay.php?pictureID=3">`. Found this (SO question)[[PHP - call a function from a img src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275273/php-call-a-function-from-a-img-src]) and (this other)[[The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385982/the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors]) but still cannot see how to fix it :-(

Answer (score 0):

I would **seriously** reconsider storing images in the database. The best method would be to save the file and have the image path in the database. If this is absolutely required try this code to save:

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

// Select file type
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Valid file extensions
$extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

// Check extension
if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

// Insert record
$query = "insert into images(name) values('".$name."')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);

// Upload file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$name);
```

And this code to display

```
$sql = "select name from images where id=1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$image = $row['name'];
$image_src = "upload/".$image;

?>
<img src='<?php echo $image_src;  ?>' >
```

This code is pulled from this example - http://makitweb.com/upload-and-store-an-image-in-the-database-with-php/#base64

You will need to modify it to work with your code.

Comment: The code I posted above is very similar to one from a textbook, which is why I am more interested exactly in how it should decently work and less in alternatives. But of course thanks for your advice and code suggestion. It's just that it's from a textbook and no errata about it on the textbook's website, so I guess it is supposed to work, but I can't figure out why I can't get it to work ? It's almost 1:1

Comment: have you tried to just display the BLOB? Use the same code but without the base64_decode() and see if that allows it to display.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="png/jpeg/jpg/image"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`enter code here`
    $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  `enter code here`
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
     // $allowed = array("pdf" => "pdf");
     // var_dump($name,$temp_name);
    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){      
            $location = './uploads1/';      
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
            //var_dump($temp_name,$location.$name);
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';

                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
echo "connect";
if(!$con)
{
die("not connect");
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"dstpurse"); 


$query="INSERT INTO `image_upload`(`name`,`path`) VALUES('$name','$location')";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($result)
{
echo "inserted";
}
else
{
echo "not inserted";
}

            }
        }       
    }  else {
        echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
    }
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `image_upload`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1) or die("query failed:".mysqli_error());
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
var_dump($name); 

echo "<a href=".$location.$name.">dowenload</a>";

}


}

?>
```

Comment: I don't look for an alternative code to get the image saved in a database and then displayed, but for the error which prevents it from being displayed with the code posted. The scheme it follows is: 1. get image content with file_get_contents(); 2. encode with base64_encode(); 3. insert into database; 4. load HTML with an <img> tag whose `src` attribute calls a PHP script and provides the image selection criterium in its URL query string; 5. the PHP script retrieves the encoded image content from the database, decodes it, and then echoes image content by defining it as image/png in header.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="png/jpeg/jpg/image"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`enter code here`
    $name       = $_FILES['file']['name'];  `enter code here`
    $temp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  
     // $allowed = array("pdf" => "pdf");
     // var_dump($name,$temp_name);
    if(isset($name)){
        if(!empty($name)){      
            $location = './uploads1/';      
            if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$name)){
            //var_dump($temp_name,$location.$name);
                echo 'File uploaded successfully';

                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
echo "connect";
if(!$con)
{
die("not connect");
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"dstpurse"); 


$query="INSERT INTO `image_upload`(`name`,`path`) VALUES('$name','$location')";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($result)
{
echo "inserted";
}
else
{
echo "not inserted";
}

            }
        }       
    }  else {
        echo 'You should select a file to upload !!';
    }
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `image_upload`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1) or die("query failed:".mysqli_error());
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
var_dump($name); 

echo "<a href=".$location.$name.">dowenload</a>";

}


}

?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation and some comments to your answer. As it is, it will not be very helpful. Also, you have some `//`ed some lines – why?